# Create MPI datatype for array of floats (C)

Tags: struct, types, mpi, openmpi

If I have an array of floats struct type, how do I create an MPI datatype for this type?

C code:

```
typedef struct
{
 float array[10];
} arraytype;
```

Found this link on the topic: http://beige.ucs.indiana.edu/I590/node100.html
and would like some help making sense of it for my question

Comment: `MPI_Type_contiguous( 10, MPI_FLOAT, &mytype)` should do it

Comment: Nice, I will try that

Comment: @Gilles could you explain what `mytype` is? I tried this and it says `mytype` is undefined - where/how do I define this? I tried it with `arraytype` as well, and this gave an error as it didn't accept the name (has an underscore in it)

Comment: `MPI_Type mytype;` and after the call to `MPI_Type_contiguous` you'll have to call `MPI_Type_commit( &mytype );`

Comment: @Giles and if MPI_Type is undefined? (sorry for all these follow-up questions)

Comment: Oops, that `MPI_Datatype`, my mistake

Comment: @Gilles Thanks, that worked. If you write it as an answer, I'll vote for it!